# composer require laravel/homestead --dev

Tags: php, macos, laravel-5, homestead

Hello I'm new to Laravel and have been trying to set up a hello world app on my MAC using this tutorial.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/homestead

When I run the command.

```
composer require laravel/homestead --dev
```

i get the following error message.

```
Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Any one know how to fix this one?

Comment: Hello Chris, have you tried to install composer first ?

Comment: is there more the error message than that?

Comment: yes i have installed composer and the full message is: Using version ^2.2 for laravel/homestead
./composer.json has been updated
> php artisan clear-compiled

Parse error: parse error, expecting `"identifier (T_STRING)"' or `"variable (T_VARIABLE)"' or `'{'' or `'$'' in /Users/chris.evans/Documents/blog/artisan on line 31
Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the pre-update-cmd event returned with an error

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.

                      
  [RuntimeException]  
  Error Output:

Comment: whats your php version.. you'll need php > 5.5.9

Comment: OK I'm running  5.4.30

Comment: Im updating to 5.6 now I'll see if that works

Comment: the virtual box is using php 7

Comment: I may be wrong but I think that is only if you are doing the global homestead. Your command is for a project specific homestead.. Either way the error you are getting is bc of a syntax error in PHP and should be fixed if you update PHP to 5.6.

Comment: I think i will switch back to running a global project with the "vagrant up" command.

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to run as a global project as MAC doesn't like PHP. Best to use the below command.

```
vagrant up
```

Or use MAMP.